# Error loading rgdal

Tags: r, linux, dll, centos, rgdal

I have successfully installed the `rgdal` package along with the dependencies GDAL and Proj4. After installation I succesfully loaded the package in R with the `library` function. However after my most recent login when i type in the command `library(rgdal)` I get an error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rgdal' in dyn.load(file, 
DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/home/nikhail1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-
library/3.4/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
libgdal.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I understand this means there is no link to the libgdal file but I am not sure how to fix it. libgdal.so.20 is in the system under /home/nikhail1/bin/gdal/lib/. The rgdal.so file is under the rgdal folder in the R library in my /home/nikhail1/ system. I do not have the authority to perform an `ldconfig` function on shared libraries (I am a novice). Does anyone have a function that could help me make the system recognize the pathway to libgdal.so.20. I am working on a Linux CentOs 6.9 system. I cannot perform any `sudo apt-get`, `yum` or `brew` functions.

Many thanks, Nikhail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `/home/nikhail1/bin/gdal/lib`, i.e. in bash

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/nikhail1/bin/gdal/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
ldd /home/nikhail1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
```

should report `libgdal.so.20` as been found. How to make this persistent depends on your desktop environment.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have fixed the first error. Now getting a similar error message saying `Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rgdal' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/nikhail1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  libproj.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: The libproj.so.9 file can be found in home/nikhail1/bin/proj-4.9.2/lib. Do i use the same command as you have suggested for libgdal.so?

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept/up-vote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I did, but because my reputation is so low the upvote is recorded but not publicly displayed. Sorry, but thank you very much nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

I've suffered quite a lot with gdal, rgdal and the proper setting of these in order to run rgdal functions in R. My bulletproof routine at the moment is the following:

UNINSTALL GDAL

```
sudo apt-get remove gdal-bin
```

Uninstall gdal-bin including dependent package

If you would like to remove gdal-bin and it's dependent packages which are no longer needed from Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gdal-bin
```

Use Purging gdal-bin
If you use with purge options to gdal-bin package all the configuration and dependent packages will be removed.

```
sudo apt-get purge gdal-bin
```

If you use purge options along with auto remove, will be removed everything regarding the package, It's really useful when you want to reinstall again.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gdal-bin
```

Just to be sure if you've tried and failed many times to install it and it doesn't work, run all of these in sequential order.

INSTALL GDAL

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin proj-bin libgdal-dev libproj-dev -y
```

INSTALL RGDAL

IN R:

```
install.packages('rgeos', type='source')

install.packages('rgdal', type='source')
```

Now everything should load and run smooth.

Comment: Thank you Momchill. I have since moved on from cluster computing in R (for now) however, I will keep this post up so helpful answers such as yours will benefit others with similar issues, which seem to be relatively persistent among even regular users of gdal.