# How to solve error when loading tidycensus library

Tags: r, package, tidyverse, tidycensus

I have a Mac with MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3. I try to use the `tidycensus` library:

```
library(tidycensus)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidycensus’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What should I do?

Comment: See if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823736/8245406) may be of help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.